# parsing xml using tag and attribute

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-serialization, xml-parsing

how to parse this xml file pasted in the url

http://pastebin.com/MpwSzYGm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-32"?>
<mp3gallery>
<albums selectAtStartItemNo = "1">
    <album id="1">
        <author><![CDATA[MORR]]></author>           
        <tracks>
            <item id="1">
                <title><![CDATA[x1]]></title>
                <song>www.gooogle.com</song>
            </item>
            <item id="2">
                <title><![CDATA[x2]]></title>
                <song>www.yahoo.com</song>
            </item>
        </tracks>
    </album>    
</albums>
```

what i need to select value "www.gooogle.com" using only the id (attribute)

example :
select(2 which is the id ) return www.yahoo.com

using javascript and hope not using jquery

thanks

Comment: Actualy using jQuery is recommended because parsing and creating XML documents differs from one browser to another. So to avoid handling that in your javaScript it is better to use a library like jQuery.

Comment: The question isn't jQuery tagged, the author asked for a non-jQuery-based answer, and yet, every single comment and answer contains the word jQuery! #meh

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Webkit browsers use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser), while IE uses [`XMLDom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx). I'd strongly recommend not reinventing the wheel and hacking together a cross-browser solution - just use jQuery.

Using jQuery, you write something like this:

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
$(xmlDoc).find("item[id='2']").attr("song");
```

Comment: if there wasn't a good solution using non-jquery code no problem to use jquery , i develop this code for a plugin for chrome so my platform intended to be using is chrome not firefox nor ie .